# Inheritance on grandfathers property

Tags: practical-islam, fiqh, inheritance

I have a question regarding inheritance.

My father had an older brother and three sisters. My grandfather passed away in 1980s and for 10 years the property wasn’t transferred to anyone’s name. During that time my grandmother was residing in that property.  My uncle transferred his share of the house to my dads name in 1995, (as a gift with no pressure) this transfer was witnessed in the court and I have documents to prove that. Following that, my uncle passed away in 1998. My grandmother passed away in 2004-5.

In 2007, my dad paid one of the other sister share in cash (based on the valuation at the time)and the other two sisters transferred their share of the house as well (as a gift) on their free will. Although my uncle had transferred his share to my dad, my dad went to my uncles widow and asked if she would like the share as he is paying the other sisters share. They declined the share. However, my dad said that when my uncles daughter got married he will help them in whatever way he can. During the next few years my dad lost touch as he was working in UAE and they were based in Pakistan. In 2014, my dad transferred the house on to his name and following that the house was transferred to me as his son. I am the only son and I have no siblings, so I am the sole owner of the property now.

All the transfers have been attested by magistrates and have witnesses and are legally binding in the eyes of law.

My father passed away in 2015, and after 20 years my uncles kids are asking for their share of the property. Are they owed anything religiously, as they are of the belief that we have been unjust to them. As I am the legal owner of the property, are they owed anything? My uncle transferred his share of the property in 1995 on his own free will and no one forced him too.  I wanted to find out if islamically anything is owed to them, considering the fact that the property is on my name now.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its asking for a fatwa for a very specific and complex situation. We don't have all the required details, nor can we verify your claims. Please consult a Mufti with details of your case to get a proper verdict. Otherwise reword the post to ask a more general question.